# Spring Roo - use file as Database

Tags: database, file

I want to use `Spring Roo` for a small Protoype.
 I want to store my data persistent, but I don't want to setup my own MYSQL (or sth else) database.
Is there a way to instruct `Roo` to use a File as Database, or another simple way to use persistent storage w/o setting up a database?

Thank you

Comment: `jpa setup --database HYPERSONIC_PERSISTENT ...`

Comment: Aleksandr, I tried this. But unfortunately, when I am input some data in my Web-Frontend and afterwards killing + starting mvn, my data disappears. Do I have to export it anyhow?

Comment: ahh.. too bad, I should have read further. Have to edit persistence.xml - with these changes it is really persistent.
Thank you!